# URL Rewrite, folder to sub domain IIS/PHP

Tags: php, url, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a folder to a sub domain on iis 7 but i dont understand what i need to add to my web.config

iis is running on server 2008 and i also have php installed, so if it is easier to do it in php .htaccess then by all means tell me.

what i need it to do is;

http://subdomain.site1.uk.com/folder1 => http://folder1.subdomain.site1.uk.com

but folder1 could be called anything, so it cant be hard coded.

i also need to access the website from http://folder1.subdomain.site1.uk.com

Comment: `.htaccess` is the apache version of `web.config`, not an option with IIS. You'll want to do it in the web.config. Do you have access to IIS manager? There's an interface there to do rewrites, I haven't worked with web.config in a while. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Yes i have access to the iis manager, i n the web platform installer it says that i do have the url rewrite 2.0 installed but i dont have an icon for it in the iis manager?